# Regex in google link params

Tags: regex

I do not have experience with regex code. 
I want take from following text

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=it&usg=AFQjCNG4x7juUilTtEDL5ae1ecsNh7E-yQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52778905305151&ei=2_utVbj7MsHS1QaH3YHQBA&url=http://time.com/3964691/yoga-dogs-and-cats/ tag:news.google.com,2005:cluster=http://time.com/3964691/yoga-dogs-and-cats/ Mon, 20 Jul 2015 17:44:50 GMT <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;"><tr><td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=it&amp;usg=AFQjCNG4x7juUilTtEDL5ae1ecsNh7E-yQ&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52778905305151&amp;ei=2_utVbj7MsHS1QaH3YHQBA&amp;url=http://time.com/3964691/yoga-dogs-and-cats/"><img src="//t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPm8SUGKyWdqCih-LdFBEVfcJI2B86tVNolZJLoeWesaK1Jss7lbJsPKhaqLe8Pap7kYdL2Xw" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80"><br><font size="-2">TIME</font></a></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br><div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1"></div><div class="lh"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=it&amp;usg=AFQjCNG4x7juUilTtEDL5ae1ecsNh7E-yQ&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52778905305151&amp;ei=2_utVbj7MsHS1QaH3YHQBA&amp;url=http://time.com/3964691/yoga-dogs-and-cats/"><b>Watch <b>cats</b> and dogs interrupt yoga routines - Time</b></a><br><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">TIME</font></b></font><br><font size="-1">The compilation above shows many a yoga routine getting interrupted. And it really never gets old watching a dog rush to the aid of his owner trapped in a headstand or for a a pet to think pigeon pose is an invitation for kisses. There&#39;s also the <b>cat</b> <b>...</b></font><br><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=it&amp;usg=AFQjCNF7ZjyL7I-LxTV8hfZo7LQ9ZAidSQ&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52778905305151&amp;ei=2_utVbj7MsHS1QaH3YHQBA&amp;url=http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2015/07/20/cats-and-dogs-interrupting-yoga_n_7830796.html"><b>Cats</b> And Dogs Interrupting Yoga - Huffington Post UK</a><font size="-1" color="#6f6f6f"><nobr>Huffington Post UK</nobr></font></font><br><font size="-1" class="p"></font><br><font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/story?ncl=dtJjhOioeLRtSJMzD7u9ebMAVfF0M&amp;ned=it&amp;hl=en"><nobr><b>tutte le notizie (3)&nbsp;&raquo;</b></nobr></a></font></div></font></td></tr></table>
```

the following string present in the text above

```
http://time.com/3964691/yoga-dogs-and-cats/
```

Comment: Which language you're using?

Comment: That text appears on multiple places, Wich one you want to take it from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<=url=).+?(?= )
```

Play around with it here: https://regex101.com/r/pO4cT3/1

Answer (score 0):

You can get this text using

```
(?<=url=)http[^\s"]+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV9hU9/2)

Note that your `(?<=url=).+?(?= )` regex matches more than the URL you need to extract:

[image]